# Get specific text from file in bash

Tags: bash

i have problem to show specific text. Example i will get only version number from text in file version.txt this:
`Version = "0.11.0"`

can someone help me?

thanks

Comment: If the string `Version` only appears once in your text file, you could get away with `grep Version version.txt`

Comment: `tr -cd '0-9.\n' < file`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `cut`:

`cut -d '=' -f2 version.txt | xargs`

Or `awk` as others suggested:

`awk '{print $3}' version.txt`

Both output:
`0.11.0`

The logic is based on the file format being consistent rather than focusing on the number extraction.
`cut` : prints the value after `=` | `xargs` : trims spaces
`awk` : prints the value on third place

These allow for example both x.x.x and x.x.x-RELEASE

Comment: No need for the `cat`, leave the `cat` alone...  here `cut -d '=' -f2 version.txt | xargs ...`  and `awk '{print $3}' version.txt`

Comment: @Jetchisel thank you for your suggestion, I updated my answer. No more `cat` :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Nice, iam use ```cut -d '=' -f2 version.txt | xargs``` to solved this, thanks you

Answer (score 1):

You want just the numbers?

Perhaps

```
awk -F\" '/Version/ {print $2}' version.txt
```

Comment: This is also filtering out other lines that might be present in the file